# Are every bytes of a file made of char from a charset?

Tags: java

I am writing a program (in Java) that has to remove half of the bytes of a file, but sequentially ie. remove every even (or uneven) byte.

I am using the following method to retrieve all the bytes :

```
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

From a text file, using `System.out.println(fileContent[i]);` it will output the corresponding ASCII code of the targeted byte.

Do I always get an ASCII code ? I don't know how the structure of a file work.

In the end, I didn't manage to make a successful loop to write in a new file by looping through `byte[] fileContent` and skip 1/2 elements.

Instead I created `char[] fileContentChar` out of `byte[] fileContent` , and write from that one.

Comment: It depends on the file you are reading. If it is an image file, then the bytes represent the pixels of the image (possibly compressed).

Comment: No, ASCII is only used in very specialized contexts. If you were using ASCII, you'd know the specification or standard that applies, such as [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to "Do I always get an ASCII code?" is: No. You cannot make any assumptions about the character encoding of a text file. There are so many formats (ASCII, UTF8, UTF16, ISO-8859-1, Unicode, etc. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding ) that you need to sample the file to make any assumptions if the text is 7 bit (ASCII) or UTF8 etc.

char and byte are not the same (in terms of bit length, depending on platform).  In java, char is 2 byte (16 bit) and byte is 1 byte (8 bit).

There are tricks to guessing what encoding a text file uses.  For example, if you sample 100 bytes and the high bit is never set, it *might* be 7-bit ASCII ( b & 0x80 ).  If the file starts with a 3 byte preamble/signature (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) it is likely UTF8. (UTF8 is 1 to 4 bytes per character; looking at the high bits of the first byte.)  Java by default uses UTF16 (2 bytes).  Check this resource for more details (http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Good luck!

Comment: The default encoding used by java is actually system-dependent (unless you're using nio). Linux and Mac use UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Dang it, you're right. Need to check Charset.defaultCharset()) and other properties.

Comment: @killjoy It might also be user-dependent and time-dependent. So the window of appropriateness and usefulness is very small.